# how to add calculated columns with condition to Propel1.6 Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, propel

Is there any way to count related columns with condition and add in the main object.
I have schema tables like:

```
-Book
-Author
-Reader
```

I Query like:

```
$readerQuery
->joinWith('book')
->useBookQuery()
    ->joinWith('author')
->endUse()
->withColumn('COUNT(Author.Id)', 'readBook')
->withColumn('COUNT(Author.Name)', 'bookByAuthorName(foo)')
->withColumn('COUNT(Author.Name)', 'bookByAuthorName(bar)')
->find()
```

I want result like:

```
id name readBooks bookByAuthorName(foo) bookByAuthorName(bar)
1  john  4                 2                   2
2  doe   6                 4                   2
```

Note:imagine simplest relations here, its is not actual problem

Comment: what is your condition here? I don't understand that questions fully. To have meaningful count values you need to group by id.

Comment: the condition is count(books read by john (and written by foo)). SO up here; 4 books are read by john out of which 2 are written by "foo" and 2 by "bar"